# Should I be making References in Fluent Nhibernate Not Nullable?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have something like this in my Map

```
public class Settings : ClassMap<Setting>
{
  References(x => x.User).Not.Nullable();
}
```

Now every time I want to save a settings I have to give it a User Object otherwise I get

> not-null property references a null or
>   transient value

My thinking was that by doing this I will enforce relational constraints. However it just seems weird that I have to pass in the whole object when really it needs to just use the Fk.

I hope it is not re-saving the whole thing internally and just adding the Fk to keep relational constraints.

So am I do this the right way?

**Edit**

```
 public class Settings : ClassMap<Setting>
 {
      Id(x => x.SettingId);
      Map(x => x.Something);
      Map(x => x.Something2);
      References(x => x.User).Not.Nullable();
 }


Public class User: ClassMap<User>
{
   Id(x => x.UserId);
   Map(x => x.FirstName);
   Map(x => x.LastName);
   HasOne(x => x.Settings);
   HasMany(x => x.AnotherTable);
}


Settings s = new Settings()
{
      Something = "142",
      Something2 = "1421414"
};

session.Create(s); // this will crash as s.User equals null;
```

I have to do this

```
User user = repo.GetUser("userId");

Settings s = new Settings()
{
      Something = "142",
      Something2 = "1421414",
      User = user
};

session.Create(s); // this should work.
```

Now I am wondering since I did User = user; Does nhibernate just grab the userId and save that into the Settings tbl or does it go through and check the user table for changes, and then checks the "another table" for changes?

Or does it do a blink update of all the fields for the user table and the another table.

Does that make sort of sense of what I mean by is it saving the whole object?

Comment: can you post a test that fails with "not-null property references a null or transient value" so we know exactly what you're doing and what you're expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't resave/update the user object. It will only get it's Id and update the Fk Column. If you wan't to know what is happening behind the scenes, you try using SQL Server Profiler (if your DB is MSSQL) or the [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/).

By the way, check this [ayende's post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/nhibernatecascadesthedifferentbetweenallalldeleteorphansandsaveupdate.aspx), it tells about different ways of save/update/delete cascades in NHibernate.

Comment: I am also wondering if I have the object already should i just use that User = user; or should I always use Load if I can?

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's mean to be done. You whould only use `.Load` when you have only the Id and know that this Id is valid.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling NHibernate to validate this property for nulls by using `.Not.Nullable()`.

Of course it will complain if it's null, with an appropriate message.

If you want it to be nullable... just don't tell it otherwise :-)

Update: I'm still have problems understanding what your concern is. If you retrieve a User instance (actually, you don't even have to go to the DB if you have the Id; just use `session.Load`) and do not change any properties, why would NHibernate "resave" it?

Comment: I don't think it is a wrong value. I think it is just mad that the object I am trying to save has a Null object of User. If I give it a User then it will save it. I already have a loaded User but Settings does not have a load user as the Setting object is made by me and not by nhibernate as I am inserting a new Setting record and not updating an existing setting record. I guess I could go and add the settings object to the User object and save that but I am wondering how to go about it this way.

Comment: @chobo2 What do you mean by "resave the whole object"? Can you post the actual code?